# What is the power consumption of a 12V adapter running 4 CPU fans?

Tags: 12v, adapter, watts, ac-dc

I have a quick question here.

I am not a ECE guy and just a hobbyist trying to tinker while quarantined.

I have 4 CPU fans (120mm) laying around and I'm trying to re-purpose them as a small fan.

I found an old 12V adapter.

The adapter's info:

- AC/DC Power Adapter
- Input: AC220V/50Hz 6.8W
- Output: DC 1.5, 12V
- Loading: continuous 350mAH

My concern is, is the wattage that it consumes less than an ordinary stand fan?

[image]

Comment: it's very hard to say how much it actually consmes from those numbers alone. also how much does your other fan consume?

Comment: @Jasen, well, based on google, an ordinary stand fan consume 35-45W at max. and a CPU fan consumws 1-2W. My concern is, if I use an adapter to run 4x CPU fan, will it normally calculate as CPU fan (is the adapter heating doesn't consume power??)

Comment: For your "loading:"  mAh makes no sense.  That's a rating you would see on a battery telling you how long you can draw how much current from it.  Did you mean mA, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

## How to calculate power

Here are the formulas to calculate power:
**P = IV = I<sup>2</sup>R = V<sup>2</sup>/R**.

As you can tell you need the resistance of the load or the current.

## Step 1: make the necessary measurements

You can measure the `Resistance` or `Current` of the circuit to find the power. I suggest you follow the resistance path as it allows you to do the calculations without hooking anything up and potentially ruining the power supply or the fans.

**Measure Resistance:**

***EDIT*** I had not thought about measuring the resistance of the motor, which would be impractical. I suggest for this application using the current method.

You will need to take a multimeter and measure the resistance of each fan. The total resistance of the circuit will depend on how the fans are wired. If you are hooking just one motor up then the resistance of that motor is the total resistance. If the motors are hooked up in series then just add up the resistance of each fan connected **(R<sub>1</sub> + R<sub>2</sub> + ...)**. If the motors are parallel use this formula: **(1/R<sub>1</sub> + 1/R<sub>2</sub> +...)<sup>-1</sup>**

**Measure Current:**

You will need to take a multimeter and measure the current of the total circuit. Ammeters have extremely low resistance so it must be hooked up in series. Take the positive terminal of the power supply and hook it up to the positive terminal of the meter. Then hook up the rest of the circuit to the negative terminal of the meter. If you follow the path of current it should form a path from the power supply to the meter to the fans then back to the power supply. Make sure you adjust your meter appropriately because they are fused at a certain level and you definitely don't want to break the fuse. For your application I would say that the mA setting should work, but to be safe start off on A and work your way down until the numbers start showing on the scale.

## Step 2: Calculations

***NOTE:*** All calculations are done in units of Volts, Amps, and Ohms. If you use mA or mV or mOhms make sure to convert your values to amps before you start calculations.

Since you know the voltage is `12V` you can use the first or last formula mentioned above, depending on if you found `resistance` or `current`. And there you go, the power! I would suggest checking for the potential problems as described below.

## Step 3: Check for potential problems

I suggest that you calculate the current of the circuit if you didn't measure it already. If you chose to measure the resistance you can use Ohm's law to calculate the current: **I = <sup>V</sup>/<sub>R</sub>**

Now that you found the current, make sure it is not greater than the current the power supply can supply or the fan(s) can handle (which can be found on datasheets if you know the model number of the fans).
***NOTE:*** Make sure you are reading the value with units A off of power supply, not Ah which is a separate unit.

(Exception if you wired the fans in parallel, where the current per fan is equal to **<sup>V</sup>/<sub>Fan Resistance</sub>**)

***EDIT:***

## Answer

Your power supply limit is `400mA` which means that the fans can not consume any more than `400mA` of current. At `12V` using the equations previously mentioned you will get about `4.8W` of power, assuming the fans use the maximum current (which is likely but not always the case). If you want to find the true power then you need to measure the current draw of the motors as described above

Comment: a multimeter will not give a good figure for the resistance of the elecrtronic motor used in the fans

Comment: @Jasen you are right I don't know why I overlooked this. I added an edit to advise to use the current method

Comment: hi, I updated my question, adding a sample image of my adapter. thanks!

Comment: @MaCheeNeraid I edited my answer to include specifics to the power adapter. It is at the bottom. No problem! If I solved your problem make sure to hit the check mark under the voting buttons to say that it is the answer.